# Get Max of date column without using summarise in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How to convert following sql query to Kusto without grouping and using summarize syntax. Thanks

SELECT Max(BirthDate) FROM [Employees]

Comment: why is the constraint of not using summarize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to get the max value of a column without using `summarize` because you want to use this value in per-record calculations.

The way to achieve this is to use a `let` statement to calculate the max value, after which you can write a query that will use the calculated value:

```
let MaxTimestamp = toscalar(MyTable | summarize max(Timestamp));
<Query with MaxTimestamp>
```

Example:

```
let MyData = datatable(Fruit: string, Count: long) [
    "banana", 30,
    "apple", 60,
    "watermelon", 20
];
let NumFruit = toscalar(MyData | summarize sum(Count));
MyData
| extend Percentage = Count * 100.0 / NumFruit
```

Result:

| Fruit | Count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | 30 | 27.2727272727273 |
| apple | 60 | 54.5454545454545 |
| watermelon | 20 | 18.1818181818182 |

Comment: I was hoping to avoid summarize for better performance but looks like not possible. Thanks mate

Comment: If `summarize` takes longer than you would expect, you can try improving it by replacing `summarize` with `summarize hint.strategy=shuffle`, or if you're summarizing by some key which has (at least) millions of different values, try `summarize hint.shufflekey=ColumnName` (and using the Partitioning policy may help too). Note: the more cluster nodes you have, the more significant the difference will be.